# Reading association extras

Tags: android, associations

This works for if I open a zip file using ES File Explorer but results a NullPointerException if I try to open the zip file using Opera Mobile.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Log.v(TAG, "file: " + extras.getString("archive_file_name"));
```

Can I get the file path reliably from external intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Log.v(TAG, "file: " + getIntent().getData().getPath());
```